# How to bind (or remap) a socket with an abstract name to a path?

Tags: socket, namespace

In our system (Linux 4.4) we see a a unix socket with an abstract namespace (those starting with @ with no corresponding file on the file system). Showing its details with lsof reports:

```
serv 7539 aesmd    6u  unix 0xffff8800795e12c0      0t0   220690 @aesm_socket_base type=STREAM
```

We would like to create a sort of alias (or symlink) on the filesystem (something like `/var/run/aesm.sock` )

Is there a way to do so ?

Comment: What are you going to use it for? In what way does it need to be an *alias* (which I think isn't possible) and not an unrelated socket with a program forwarding between them (which is definitely possible)?

Comment: It can be an unrelated socket, as long as it forwards all the actions (connection attempts and traffic) to the original one. The resulting, file-system based socket /var/run/aesm.sock is going to be made accessible from inside a docker container via the usual volume mounting approach.

Answer (score 4):

You can forward between just about any kind of sockets and other communication channels with [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/). Listen to connections on the file-named socket, forward them to the abstract-named socket, forking to handle concurrent connections. I think this should do the trick (untested):

```
socat UNIX-LISTEN:/var/run/aesm.sock,fork ABSTRACT-CONNECT:aesm_socket_base
```